# translate sql to linq with Where and GroupBY

Tags: c#, sql, linq

SQL:

```
SELECT  
p.PipelineID
, MAX(PipelineJobStatus.CreatedTimeStamp)
, Client.ClientName
, FCO.NameFCO
, p.ProjectValueHr
, p.ProjectValueMoney
, p.CommentPipeline
, PipelineJobStatus.CreatedTimeSTamp
, p.ModifiedTimeStamp
, Employee.Name
, Employee.Surname
, JobStatus.JobStatusName
FROM (Pipeline p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PipelineJobStatus ON p.PipelineID = PipelineJobStatus.PipelineID)
INNER JOIN JobStatus ON (PipelineJobStatus.JobStatusID = JobStatus.JobStatusID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON (p.ClientID = Client.ClientID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN FCO ON (p.FCOID = FCO.FCOID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee ON (p.CreatedBy = Employee.EmployeeD)
WHERE PipelineJobStatus.CreatedTimeStamp IN 
   (SELECT MAX(CreatedTimeStamp) FROM PipelineJobStatus GROUP BY PipelineID)
GROUP BY p.PipelineID
, Client.ClientName
, FCO.NameFCO
, p.ProjectValueHr
, p.ProjectValueMoney
, p.CommentPipeline
, PipelineJobStatus.CreatedTimeSTamp
, p.ModifiedTimeStamp
, Employee.Name
, Employee.Surname
, JobStatus.JobStatusName
```

I've tried LINQ:

```
 from pjs in db.PipelineJobStatus
 //.OrderByDescending(p=>p.CreatedTimeStamp)
 //.DistinctBy(p => p.PipelineID)
 //.FirstOrDefault()
 from pipe in db.Pipelines
    .Where(pipe => pipe.PipelineID == pjs.PipelineID).DefaultIfEmpty()
 from status in db.JobStatus
    .Where(statuses => statuses.JobStatusID == pjs.JobStatusID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
 from fco in db.FCOes
    .Where(fcoes => fcoes.FCOID == pipe.FCOID)
 from client in db.Clients
    .Where(clients => clients.ClientID == pipe.ClientID)
    //Where PipelineJobStatus.CreatedTimeStamp in (select max(CreatedTimeStamp) from PipelineJobStatus group by PipelineID)
    .Where(pjs.CreatedTimeStamp in select Max(pjs.CreatedTimeStamp)from PipelineJobStatus group by)
  group by { pipe.PipelineID } //group new
          by new
          {
              status.JobStatusName,
              pipe.PipelineID,
              pipe.ClientID,
              client.ClientName,
              fco.NameFCO,
              fco.FCOID,
              pipe.Employee.Name,
              pipe.Employee.Surname,
              pipe.CommentPipeline,
              pipe.CreatedBy,
              pipe.CreatedTimeStamp,
              pipe.ModifiedTimeStamp,
              pipe.ProjectValueHr,
              pipe.ProjectValueMoney
          } into g

           orderby g.Key.PipelineID descending

           select new StatusPipelineMerge
           {
               PipelineID = g.Key.PipelineID,
               ProjectValueHr = g.Key.ProjectValueHr,
               ProjectValueMoney = g.Key.ProjectValueMoney,
               CommentPipeline = g.Key.CommentPipeline,
               ClientName = g.Key.ClientName,
               FCOName = g.Key.NameFCO,
               FCOID = g.Key.FCOID,
               ClientID = g.Key.ClientID,
               CreatedTimeStamp = g.Key.CreatedTimeStamp,
               ModifiedTimeStamp = g.Key.ModifiedTimeStamp,
               CreatedBy = g.Key.CreatedBy,
               //CreatedNameSurname = g.Key.Employee.Name + " " + g.Key.Employee.Surname
               JobStatusName = g.Key.JobStatusName
           }
```

`.Where()` clause is underlined with red..

Where I am wrong?

P.S. SQL is working
I will change this chained tables, with joins, for now I just want to work.

Maybe store procedure is not lousy option here.

Comment: Just thought - maybe its easier to create Stored Procedure or View in database for that? I bet it will be more efficient and easier to understand by other developers. Because such linq queries just unmaintainable. You can call SP from EF or Linq to SQL.

Comment: why u want to use linq? SQL is always faster

Comment: @Viru Probably updating an old project to use Entity Framework to remove potentially error-prone code with tested and managed code for translating SQL rows to C# objects. It increases testability and improves development time.

Comment: SQL in your code is always harder to maintain, and harder to secure, than objects that can be refactored. And I am not sure I agree with the fact that SQL is always faster. You have to maintain your own DataReaders etc.. messy.

Comment: In terms of performance, SQL is faster but Yes, I agree if you consider code maintenance and testability then EF is much better....

Comment: I agree, but in this step I want to make linq to work...but it doesnt..

Comment: I have some issues with stored procedure..it throws me an exception